# Count the Number of Zero's between Range of integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

. Is there any Direct formula or System to find out the Numbers of Zero's between a Distinct Range ... Let two Integer M & N are given . if I have to find out the total number of zero's between this Range then what should I have to do ?

Let M = 1234567890 & N = 2345678901
And answer is : 987654304

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Yes .... More Precisely .. Between M and N ... How many ' 0 ' digits are Exist . @mvw

Comment: Hey I want to find the Number of ' 0 ' Digits between a Specific Range @mvw

Comment: I added an answer which solves your problem.

Comment: This might have been taken from [here](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1979). I needed more than 3000s, btw.

Answer (score 3):

**Reexamining the Problem**

Here is a simple solution in Ruby, which inspects each integer from the interval [m,n], determines the string of its digits in the standard base 10 positional system, and counts the occuring 0 digits:

```ruby
def brute_force(m, n)
  if m > n
    return 0
  end
  z = 0
  m.upto(n) do |k|
    z += k.to_s.count('0')
  end
  z
end
```

If you run it in an interactive Ruby shell you will get

```ruby
irb> brute_force(1,100)
=> 11
```

which is fine. However using the interval bounds from the example in the question

```ruby
m = 1234567890
n = 2345678901
```

you will recognize that this will take considerable time. On my machine it does need more than a couple of seconds, I had to cancel it so far.

So the real question is not only to come up with the correct zero counts but to do it faster than the above brute force solution.

**Complexity: Running Time**

The brute force solution needs to perform n-m+1 times searching the base 10 string for the number k, which is of length floor(log_10(k))+1, so it will not use more than

> O(n (log(n)+1))

string digit accesses. The slow example had an n of roughly n = 10^9.

**Reducing Complexity**

Yiming Rong's answer is a first attempt to reduce the complexity of the problem.

If the function for calculating the number of zeros regarding the interval [m,n] is F(m,n), then it has the property

> F(m,n) = F(1,n) - F(1,m-1)

so that it suffices to look for a most likely simpler function G with the property

> G(n) = F(1,n).

**Divide and Conquer**

Coming up with a closed formula for the function G is not that easy. E.g.
the interval [1,1000] contains 192 zeros, but the interval [1001,2000] contains 300 zeros, because a case like k = 99 in the first interval would correspond to k = 1099 in the second interval, which yields another zero digit to count. k=7 would show up as 1007, yielding two more zeros.

What one can try is to express the solution for some problem instance in terms of solutions to simpler problem instances. This strategy is called divide and conquer in computer science. It works if at some complexity level it is possible to solve the problem instance and if one can deduce the solution of a more complex problem from the solutions of the simpler ones. This naturally leads to a recursive formulation.

E.g. we can formulate a solution for a restricted version of G, which is only working for some of the arguments. We call it g and it is defined for 9, 99, 999, etc. and will be equal to G for these arguments. 
It can be calculated using this recursive function:

```ruby
# zeros for 1..n, where n = (10^k)-1: 0, 9, 99, 999, ..
def g(n)
  if n <= 9
    return 0
  end
  n2 = (n - 9) / 10
  return 10 * g(n2) + n2
end
```

Note that this function is much faster than the brute force method: To count the zeros in the interval [1, 10^9-1], which is comparable to the m from the question, it just needs 9 calls, its complexity is

> O(log(n))

Again note that this g is not defined for arbitrary n, only for n = (10^k)-1.

**Derivation of g**

It starts with finding the recursive definition of the function h(n),
which counts zeros in the numbers from 1 to n = (10^k) - 1, if the decimal representation has leading zeros.

Example: h(999) counts the zero digits for the number representations:

- 001..009
- 010..099
- 100..999

The result would be h(999) = 297.

Using k = floor(log10(n+1)), k2 = k - 1, n2 = (10^k2) - 1 = (n-9)/10 the function h turns out to be

> h(n) = 9 [k2 + h(n2)] + h(n2) + n2 = 9 k2 + 10 h(n2) + n2

with the initial condition h(0) = 0. It allows to formulate g as

> g(n) = 9 [k2 + h(n2)] + g(n2)

with the intital condition g(0) = 0.

From these two definitions we can define the difference d between h and g as well, again as a recursive function:

> d(n) = h(n) - g(n) = h(n2) - g(n2) + n2 = d(n2) + n2

with the initial condition d(0) = 0. Trying some examples leads to a geometric series, e.g. d(9999) = d(999) + 999 = d(99) + 99 + 999 = d(9) + 9 + 99 + 999 = 0 + 9 + 99 + 999 = (10^0)-1 + (10^1)-1 + (10^2)-1 + (10^3)-1 = (10^4 - 1)/(10-1) - 4. This gives the closed form

> d(n) = n/9 - k

This allows us to express g in terms of g only:

> g(n) = 9 [k2 + h(n2)] + g(n2) = 9 [k2 + g(n2) + d(n2)] + g(n2) = 9 k2 + 9 d(n2) + 10 g(n2) = 9 k2 + n2 - 9 k2 + 10 g(n2) = 10 g(n2) + n2

**Derivation of G**

Using the above definitions and naming the k digits of the representation q_k, q_k2, .., q2, q1 we first extend h into H:

> H(q_k q_k2..q_1) = q_k [k2 + h(n2)] + r (k2-kr) + H(q_kr..q_1) + n2

with initial condition H(q_1) = 0 for q_1 <= 9.

Note the additional definition r = q_kr..q_1. To understand why it is needed look at the example H(901), where the next level call to H is H(1), which means that the digit string length shrinks from k=3 to kr=1, needing an additional padding with r (k2-kr) zero digits.

Using this, we can extend g to G as well:

> G(q_k q_k2..q_1) = (q_k-1) [k2 + h(n2)] + k2 + r (k2-kr) + H(q_kr..q_1) + g(n2)

with initial condition G(q_1) = 0 for q_1 <= 9.

Note: It is likely that one can simplify the above expressions like in case of g above. E.g. trying to express G just in terms of G and not using h and H. I might do this in the future. The above is already enough to implement a fast zero calculation.

**Test Result**

```ruby
recursive(1234567890, 2345678901) =
  987654304
expected:
  987654304
success
```

See the [source](https://gist.github.com/c383267928206f3cd957) and [log](https://gist.github.com/c7a44060895a24b962b3) for details.

Update: I changed the source and log according to the more detailed problem description from that contest (allowing 0 as input, handling invalid inputs, 2nd larger example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standard approach to find *m = [1, M-1]* and *n = [1, N]*, then *[M, N] = n - m*.

Standard approaches are easily available: [Counting zeroes](http://blog.codility.com/2011/12/mu-2011-certificate-solution.html).

Comment: Hey I didn't understand clearly this procedure .. Can y0u please explain ?? @Yimin Rong